# How to update an entity before calling saveChanges?

Tags: breeze

I'm calling my breezeController, getting products from Northwind. I've read you can track changes on entities and save all changes on the remote service calling **saveChanges()**.

What I haven't found is how you update entity properties. How would I change the ProductName of the ProductID(1)?

Note: I'm not using Knockout nor AngularJS. It's a plain HTML file.

I call:

```
var loadProducts = function(categoryID) {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery
        .from("Products")
        .where("CategoryID", "eq", categoryID)
        .orderBy("ProductName");

    return manager.executeQuery(query);
}

loadProducts(value).then(function (data) {
    $("#tableBody").empty();
    data.results.forEach(function (item) {
        console.log(item.ProductName);
    });
}).fail(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

What do I need to do before calling **saveChanges()**?

**EDIT => SOLUTION:**

What I ended up using was **getEntityByKey()** to modify a specific entity.

```
var productToModify;
managerProducts = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);
```

Functions:

```
var loadProducts = function (categoryID) {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery
        .from("Products")
        .where("CategoryID", "eq", categoryID)
        .orderBy("ProductName");

    return managerProducts.executeQuery(query);
}

var loadProductByID = function (productID) {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery
        .from("Products")
        .where("ProductID", "eq", productID);

    return managerProducts.executeQueryLocally(query);
}
```

Calls

```
// Called when clicking edit on table item. Load a form for edit
$("#tableBody").on("click", ".edit", function () {
    productToModify = $(this).closest(".trow").attr("id");
    var product = loadProductByID(productToModify);
    console.log(productToModify);

    $("#txtPN").val(product[0].ProductName);
    $("#txtSID").val(product[0].SupplierID);
    $("#txtUP").val(product[0].UnitPrice);
    $("#txtUIS").val(product[0].UnitsInStock);
    $("#txtUOO").val(product[0].UnitsOnOrder);
    $("#txtD").val(product[0].Discontinued);

    $(".table").fadeOut(200, function () {
        $("#editProduct").fadeIn(200);
    });
});

$("#btnSave").on("click", function () {
    if ($("#selectSupplier").val() === "0") {
        alert("Must select supplier");
    }
    else {
        console.log(productToModify);
        var product = managerProducts.getEntityByKey("Product", productToModify);
        product.ProductName = $("#txtPN").val();
        product.SupplierID = $("#txtSID").val();
        product.UnitPrice = $("#txtUP").val();
        product.UnitsInStock = $("#txtUIS").val();
        product.UnitsOnOrder = $("#txtUOO").val();
        product.Discontinued = $("#txtD").val();
        console.log(product.entityAspect.entityState.name);

        managerProducts.saveChanges().then(function () {
            $("#" + productToModify).children(".pn").text($("#txtPN").val());
            $("#" + productToModify).children(".psid").text($("#selectSupplier").val());
            $("#" + productToModify).children(".pup").text($("#txtUP").val());
            $("#" + productToModify).children(".puis").text($("#txtUIS").val());
            $("#" + productToModify).children(".puoo").text($("#txtUOO").val());
            $("#" + productToModify).children(".pd").text($("#txtD").val());

            $("#editProduct").fadeOut(200, function () {
                $(".table").fadeIn(200);
            });
        }).fail(function (e) {
            alert(e);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to update this on the client or on the server side?  Also I don't see a save method are you forgetting to show this somewhere?

Comment: If I'm correct, when using Breeze, I first need to save changes on the client side through my EntityManager. After that, I just have to call manager.saveChanges();
What I don't know how to do is update entities on the client side, before calling the manager.saveChanges(). If I call saveChanges ater the above code, nothing would happend, because EntityManager has detected no changes to the local data.

Comment: So you are using the default adapter I assume if not using KO or Angular...  I will add a quick answer but I need some more info probably...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign the new value to the entity:

```
entityToUpdate = data[0];
entityToUpdate.ProductName = 'new value' // entityToUpdate.entityAspect.entityState is updated
manager.saveChanges().then(...) // send data to the server
```

Breeze documentation is excellent: http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_saveChanges

Answer (score 2):

If you have the ability to foreEach over your data like you are when the promise is returned this is what I would try first -

```
data.results.forEach(function (item) {
    item.ProductName = "New Product Name";
    console.log('Changes ? - ', item.entityAspect.entityState);
});
```

Which if you are properly setting the product name should output Changes ? - `isModified`